# Setting up a classing using string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't get the below to work if I change this to integer and setup a scenario for grades no issue, could anyone assist with the below?

```
puts("Select a group")
group = gets
group then string(group)
case group
when group("A") then ("First")
when group("B") then ("Second")
when group("C") then ("Third")
end
puts("You are in group "+ group)
```

Comment: the code contains syntax error? what is `group then string(group)` going to do? and what is `group("A")`?

Comment: What's `when group("A")` supposed to mean, given that `group` is a **string**?

Answer (score 0):

Not going to go through each of your errors one-by-one. Rather I'd recommend you go through the fundamentals of the Ruby language (codeacademy or something). You have to be *really* specific when programming, use the exact correct syntax and *no typos*.

Anyway, here's how you could write this functionality successfully:

```
puts("Select a group")
group = case gets.chomp
when "A" then "First"
when "B" then "Second"
when "C" then "Third"
end
puts "you are in group: #{group}"
```